# How to DELETE in one batch, but different changeset?

Tags: sapui5

I am using `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel` and trying to delete multiple object. Desire result is DELETE requests are in one batch, but different changeset. Because if I wrap them up in the same changeset, one request failed will cause others to rollback.

I've tried to use `setDeferredGroups`, but it results in two batches.

```
oModel.setDeferredGroups(["group1"]);
oModel.setDeferredGroups(["group2"]);

oModel.remove("/EquipmentSet('1')", {groupId: "group1"});
oModel.remove("/EquipmentSet('2')", {groupId: "group2"});

oModel.submitChanges({
    groupId: "group1",
    success: this.successCallback, 
    error: this.errorCallback
});

oModel.submitChanges({
    groupId: "group2",
    success: this.successCallback, 
    error: this.errorCallback
});
```

And also tried [setChangeGroups](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/setChangeGroups), it still results in two batches. I did not quiet understand what's the difference between groupId and changeSetId. And what's the use of EntityTypeName?

```
oModel.setChangeGroups({
    "EntityTypeName": {
        groupId: "group1",
        changeSetId: "changeSet1",
        single: true
    }
});
oModel.setChangeGroups({
    "EntityTypeName": {
        groupId: "group2",
        changeSetId: "changeSet2",
        single: true
    }
});

oModel.remove("/EquipmentSet('1')", {groupId: "group1"});
oModel.remove("/EquipmentSet('2')", {groupId: "group2"});

oModel.submitChanges({
    success: this.successCallback, 
    error: this.errorCallback
});
```

Comment: Have you tried the same groupId, and different changeSetId in your first approach? Same groupId would ensure one batch request.

Comment: @Allen, thx! Fixed this problem by `oModel.remove("/EquipmentSet('1')", {groupId: "group1", changeSetId: "changeSetId1"});`

Comment: I am glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Allen, problem fixed

```
oModel.setDeferredGroups(["group1"]);

oModel.remove("/EquipmentSet('1')", {
     groupId: "group1", 
     changeSetId: "changeSetId1, 
     success: this.successCallback, 
     error: this.errorCallback
});

oModel.remove("/EquipmentSet('2')", {
     groupId: "group1", 
     changeSetId: "changeSetId1, 
     success: this.successCallback, 
     error: this.errorCallback
});

oModel.submitChanges({
    groupId: "group1"
});
```

And callback will no longer be caught by `submitChanges()`, it is caught by each `remove()`.

Ref: [OData V2 Model remove()](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/remove)